# How To Calling to Phonegap plugins from within the InAppBrowser?

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Now i develop a news app with Phonegap aka Cordova 3.5 , how to call Phonegap plugin like dialog plugin in InAppBrowser ? is it possible ?

Example :

i call a new detail in an InAppBrowser  , and i want to show a dialog with cordova dialog plugin .

Comment: Tell us what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Example :

i call a new detail in an InAppBrowser , and i want to show a dialog with cordova dialog plugin .

Comment: What a detail? You click on a link? Is that your own website?

Comment: yes , when i click a new preview -> cordova open new window , with news detail content

Answer (score 2):

There is still no elegant way and only once. Only pooling from In-app browser using a remote script that asks periodically to launch the close event.

From reference:
http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser